# Pronunciation of Ancient Greek sigma as voiced [z] before voiced consonants

Tags: pronunciation, ancient-greek

Throughout the development of Ancient Greek, was σ ever pronounced as [z], perhaps when before a voiced consonant, as in ἄσβεστος?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there is evidence of this in the form of spelling confusion between Σ and Ζ before voiced consonants, which in certain contexts made its mark on Latin forms (take a look at the 98 examples of [word-initial "zm"](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=zm) in the PHI Latin texts corpus, which appear in words taken from Greek that also have spellings with Σ, such as Zmyrna = [Ζμύρνα](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/%CE%B6%CE%BC%CF%8D%CF%81%CE%BD%CE%B1) = [Σμύρνα](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/%CE%A3%CE%BC%CF%8D%CF%81%CE%BD%CE%B1)).

Actually, confusion between these letters seems to have occurred even in other contexts, where it might not have always indicated identical pronunciation but just similarity. I can't give a great summary of this, but per Sturtevant 1920:[190](https://books.google.com/books?id=wWcwAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA190)

> Beginning with the year 340 B.C., Attic inscriptions show confusion between σ and ζ

(*The pronunciation of Greek and Latin: the sounds and accents*)